# Loading numpy arrays stored in npz archive in PySpark

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large number of numpy arrays in S3 stored in npz archive. What is the best way to load them into a PySpark RDD/Dataframe of NumPy arrays? I have tried to load the file using the sc.wholeTextFiles API.

```
rdd=sc.wholeTextFiles("s3://[bucket]/[folder_containing_npz_files]")
```

However numpy.load requires a file handle. And loading the file contents in memory as a string takes up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do much about memory requirements but otherwise `BytesIO` should work just fine:

```
from io import BytesIO

def extract(kv):
    k, v = kv
    with BytesIO(v) as r:
        for f, x in np.load(r).items():
            yield "{0}\t{1}".format(k, f), x

sc.binaryFiles(inputPath).flatMap(extract)
```